# Autolayout messing up my moving images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I finished a successful app and I am trying to make it compatible with all device sizes. Problem is that when I try the autolayout method, a problem happens.

I am trying to move an image with:

```
IMAGENAME.center = CGPointMake(IMAGENAME.center.x, IMAGENAME.center.y + 10);
```

Then I have many other images also moving down, its like you have to catch the falling fruits. Now, here's the issue. With autolayout turned on, when ONE fruit hits either the ground or I catch it with the basket in my game, the other fruits, including the one that hits, teleport back to where they originally started, instead of moving to the coordinates I set them to go with this code for example.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(IMAGENAME.frame, Basket.frame) {

     IMAGENAME.center = CGPointMake(600, 200);
}
```

That is the location that image is supposed to go to, but autolayout prevents that. But I want to make it universal, and I can't find another tutorial that supports the "old way", so can someone tell me what to do with autolayout or tell me how to make it universal without autolayout?

Answer (score 0):

If you use auto-layout then you have to go with it all the way.
This means not to manipulate frames (this is what .center does) in the code.

You wrote that you "turn on" the Autolayout.
Do you mean in Storyboard?
In case it is a storyboard you will have to create IBOutlet properties for the relevant constraints and connect the constraints in storyboard to the outlets (together with the image views).

Anyway, if you want to use Autolayout and to move views in code then it has to be done with constraints.
Each constraint has `constant` property that you can change in code.
For your case, in order to move the image by x and by y you will have to change 2 constraints (one horizontal and one vertical).

If it's convenient for you to manipulate center then you might create horizontal center in parent and vertical center in parent constraints.
To avoid making big changes to your existing logic you can setup the constraints according to parent left/top (rather than center).
This way the `constant` values will have to be changes with exactly the same values as you use in `IMAGENAME.center = CGPointMake(600, 200);` - instead of this you will have something like:

```
imageHorizontalCenterConstraint.constant = 600;
imageVerticalCenterConstraint.constant = 200;
[imageView.superview updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable autolayout
Doesn't work

```
1. view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)
2. view.center = CGPointMake(150, 50)
```

Need to do:
Example to change center of a view:
Add center horizontally and center vertically constraints to the view in Xib or storyboard. Make those constraints as IBOutlet in .m file.

Update center position as follows:

```
viewCenterHZConstraint.constant = 600;
viewCenterVTConstraint.constant = 200;
[self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```